# d3js v5 Add Curve kernel density estimator

Tags: javascript, d3.js

According to this example : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4341954, I try to do the same thing : show a histogram and a kernel density estimation.
Data, axis, bins and histogram seem perfect but I have a trouble when I want to add the curve.
[image]

Indeed, the second key of the variable "density" is always equal to zero.
My hypothesis : I should calculate the density with value0 and not all the data.

```
let density = kde(kernelEpanechnikov(7), x.ticks(100))(data)
```

I'm not friendy with this syntax. How can I fix that ?

Here is my code : https://plnkr.co/edit/7mvcmLdn95PU4dSmQqpP?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example Mike's data is an array of plain numbers:

```
[79,54,74,62,85,55,88,85,51,85,54,84,78,47,83,52,62,84,52,79,51,47,78,69,...
```

Here: `kde(kernelEpanechnikov(7), x.ticks(100))(data)` he passes that array to the kernel density estimator.

Your data is an array of objects, the objects themselves can't be used to specify a density with your kernel density function. If you pass an array of numbers however, you'll get a result, eg:

```
let density = kde(kernelEpanechnikov(7), x.ticks(100))
                ( data.map(function(d){  return d.value0; }) )
```